# Stack site for reviewing of academic paper preprints?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have a preprint of a paper which I intend to only upload to my personal webpage.

My question is: does a site similar to https://codereview.stackexchange.com exist for requesting review of a preprint?

I haven't heard of anything like this (other than journals reviewing potential papers and giving authors feedback, of course).